# Secure form handling using stmt prepare

Tags: php

The prepare function is not recognizing members that already exist in the DB and as a result, always calls the function NewUser() when it is supposed to go through the else statement? I believe this is because when I ask it to verify the password, it encounters an error, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong?

```
function NewUser(){
                    global $dbh;
                    $fullname = trim($_POST['fullname']); //at a minimus clear whitespace.
                    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                    $user_password =  trim($_POST['password']);
                    $options = [
                        'cost' => 12, //higher = more lower= less. you want it to take around 0.4 seconds for security reasons!
                    ];

                    $hashed_password = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options); // hashed password for storage!
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS(fullname, username, email, password) VALUES('$fullname', '$username', '$email', '$hashed_password')");
                    $stmt->bindValue(1,$fullname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(2,$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(3,$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(4,$user_password,PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    if($stmt->execute()){

                        echo "<div class= container>","<div class = \" col-md-2 connout slideInTop\">"," <span class = \"username_text\">$username</span>, <br> welcome to <br> the <br> <span class = \"vibecourt_text\">VIBECOURT</span> family! <br><br> You may <br> now sign in <br> below","</div>","</div>";
                    }
            }

            function SignUp(){

            global $dbh;

            //checking the 'user' name which is from index.php, is it empty or have some text

            if(!empty($_POST['username'])){

                    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
                    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE (username = ? AND password = ?)");
                    $stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    //check password agaisnt stored hash
                    if(!password_verify($password, $selected_row['password'])) {    
                        NewUser(); 
                    }

                    else{
                        echo("<script>location.href = 'pages/home/home.php'</script>");
                    }
            }
            }   
            SignUp();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In light of what transpired in comments... it appears the issue is further rooted far above where you are originally storing the hashed password into the database.

You say you are using a `varchar(50)`, for a `password_hash` value. This is too short, and mysql is no doubt clipping the `INSERT`. This will result in hashes that can never be matched.

You should have a `varchar(60)` at the very minimum, but PHP.net states that this hash can grow over time, and using a `varchar(255)` is recommended.

---

In this bit:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE (username = ? AND password = ?)");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $_POST['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $_POST['password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

You are trying to match the hashed value in the database, with a user inputted password (which is not hashed).

You should simply remove the `AND password = ?` and `bindValue` for it. That way it pulls a matching username entry from the db, and THEN does `password_verify` to determine if the user inputted password, matches:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!password_verify($password, $selected_row['password'])) {    
    NewUser(); 
}
```

Side note: Although I'm not sure you really WANT to make a new user if they simply typed in the wrong password??? Surely you would handle that differently. Telling them they entered a wrong password and should try again.

**EDIT**

Also in your NewUser function you have this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS(fullname, username, email, password) 
                       VALUES('$fullname', '$username', '$email', '$hashed_password')");
```

It should be this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS(fullname, username, email, password) 
                       VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
// ...
$stmt->bindValue(4,$hashed_password,PDO::PARAM_STR);// <- use $hashed_password
```

Comment: Even with the changes it adds a new hashed password to the DB and does not compare and check the hashed password to the one stored within the DB? It has to be within the password_verify() function... right?

Comment: Hm. Well then that means either the user didn't enter the right password, or the right username... or that the original hashing of the password is incorrect, so that the verify will never work. Or maybe the database password field is clipping the values (not a big enough varchar?). I dont know, there are too many unknowns outside of what you provided. I just pointed out the issues in what you provided which should work out better. Sorry it wasnt helpful.

Comment: Yeah, the VARCHAR is set to 50 and the username was entered the same way, it just duplicates it as a new entry into the DB when I try to verify... I think there is definitely a problem with the original hashing of the password

Comment: Thank you though !

Comment: From PHP.net: "Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice)."

Comment: Yup, how stupid of me, I didn't even think of the hash value being an issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well its good you figured it out! That least puts a bunch of issues at rest and you can move forward.